# I have a question about a gerund ( V+ing )

Tags: gerunds

I learned **gerund** couldn't be used this way - For example :

> Smoking that could be very harmful for my health is my big problem. (grammatically wrong)

```
= Smoking could be very harmful for my health + smoking is my big problem.
```

> Walking that I do everyday is my habit. (grammatically wrong)

```
  =  I walk everyday + walking is my habit.
```

Only with a **none** not a **gerund**.

Is it true ?

Because It makes sense at least for me.

Comment: I think those sentences are grammatical (it'd be better to wait for a more proficient speaker to decide that nonetheless), but I wonder if they convey what you intend. Please [edit] your question to clarify the intended meaning of those sentences.

Comment: ohh thank you for advise ..! I will right now :>>

Comment: Both sentences are obviously grammatical if you add some punctuation. (Commas, hyphens, or parentheses around *that* and *is*.) Since punctuation, or the lack of it, only affects semantics or style, that means that the sentences are grammatical *without* any punctuation too. (Albeit awkward.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are at least partly right.

Without the restrictive relative, it is fine:

> Walking is my habit.

With a non-restrictive relative, it is also fine:

> Walking, which I do every day, is my habit.

(That is perhaps tautologous, as "which I do every day" is almost a definition of "habit"; but that doesn't alter the fact that it is grammatical.

But with a restrictive relative clause, it is certainly awkward. I don't think it is ungrammatical: I can imagine it in rather stilted, formal language, eg:

> Talking that is not necessary should be avoided.

[Note incidentally that other modifiers which are not relative clauses can come there:

> Walking in the hills restores my good humour.
>
> Driving without care and attention is dangerous.

I believe that these work because the modifier goes inside the gerund clause:

> [Driving [without care and attention]]<sub>NP</sub> is dangerous.

But I haven't explored this point any further.]

Comment: Oh Thank you for comment Colin fine :)
so I should add something if I want tn make perfect sentence between that and is.
Thank you !

Comment: I don't understand that comment, @ukwon95.